# OpenStack persistence after a reboot

Tags: 16.04, openstack, reboot

I am new to openstack. I installed openstack using devstack all on one server (for testing). All was well after installation but when I rebooted the server then openstack failed to work. Is this a normal issue? Is there additional steps to the installation so that my cloud installation survives a reboot?

I used [this guide](http://serenity-networks.com/install-openstack-on-one-virtual-machine-the-easy-way-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) to install openstack on a single Ubuntu 16.04 server for testing and development:

This installation was installed on a FRESH install of Ubuntu 16.04 with all updates and upgrades applied. The only additional package installed outside of the default package of Ubuntu 16.04 was `openssh-server`.

After installation of Openstack (without rebooting) I was able to traverse all of the functions of the dashboard. I then shutdown for the evening. When I started up the next morning and started the dashboard I noticed many error messages (not able to retrieve usage data...etc...) but the big error was on
**Projects > Access and Security** where I received the following error message:

```
ConnectionFailed at /project/access_and_security/

Connection to neutron failed: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.8', port=9696): Max retries exceeded with url: //v2.0/extensions.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2551657850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.8/dashboard/project/access_and_security/
Django Version:     1.8.14
Exception Type:     ConnectionFailed
Exception Value:    

Connection to neutron failed: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.8', port=9696): Max retries exceeded with url: //v2.0/extensions.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2551657850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/client.py in _cs_request, line 111
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.12
Python Path:    

['/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../..',
 '/opt/stack/horizon',
 '/opt/stack/keystone',
 '/opt/stack/glance',
 '/opt/stack/cinder',
 '/opt/stack/neutron',
 '/opt/stack/nova',
 '/opt/stack/horizon',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard']

Server time:    Sun, 27 Aug 2017 18:10:22 +0000
```

I have reproduced this 5 times, each time re-installing Linux and OpenStack fresh and rebooting. Each time I receive the error above.

I noticed there is NO `/var/log/neutron` directory so I do not know where the error logs are.

Comment: I used this exact procedure.

Comment: OpenStack has a number of `systemd` services. Make sure you enabled them.

Comment: I noticed this was closed as unclear. I do not understand why. I edited my original update to include a clear procedure and error results. I the same question applies. Why does a devstack not survive a reboot?

Comment: Did you make sure you enabled the `systemd` services? Most packages don't enable them by default

Answer (score 0):

Devstack is not persistent. It was not intended to run after a reboot. If you want a simpler tool to try Openstack try Packstack (RHEL/CENTOS), if you want for an Ubuntu environment try Openstack Training Labs or Clojure-Up.These projects should help you.